# Immutable .toArray() wont render data - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, semantic-ui, immutable.js

I am mapping over some data and I am trying to use some of the data as the options for the semantic-ui-react Dropdown component, but the data wont load in even if I add `.toArray()` to the end of it, however if I change the data structure to not use Immutable, it works fine. I mainly wanted to understand why so I could get a better understanding of things.

Here is the mapping of the data with immutable:

```js
          {
            labelingData.map((item, i) => {
              return (
                <span key={i}>
                  {
                    item.get('categories').map((category, c) => {
                      return (
                        <span key={c}>
                          {
                            category.get('subcategories').map((subcategory, sc) => {
                              return (
                                <span key={sc}>
                                  {
                                    subcategory.get('name') === 'Labels'
                                    ? <Dropdown
                                        defaultValue={'Bananas'}
                                        options={subcategory.get('childItems').toArray()}
                                      />
                                    : null
                                  }
                                </span>
                              );
                            })
                          }
                        </span>
                      );
                    })
                  }
                </span>
              );
            })
          }
```

I do get an error in the console about unknown props but I am not adding these props in my code:

`` Unknown props `_root`, `__ownerID`, `__hash`, `__altered` on <div> tag. Remove these props from the element ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [api of semantic-ui-react](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown) Dropdown options is to pass in an array of objects that look like:

```
{ text: '', value: '' }
```

However, when you call `.toArray()` on a `Immutable.List` containing some `Immutable.Map` it will not `.toJS()` the Maps.

eg.

```
var list = Immutable.fromJS({ value: 1 }, 2]);
console.log(list.toArray()); // prints [Immutable.Map, 2]
```

So you are actually giving Dropdown an array of Maps and the Dropdown doesn't use `.get` to get the values from the object.

Another thing is that React prefers to receive arrays rather than immutable.Lists.

So you could use a reduce function rather than a map function to create a normal array of react components:

```
item.get('categories').reduce((result, category, c) => {
  result.push(<Category key={c} category={category} />);
  return result;
}, []);
```

Comment: This was exactly it. Changing `toArray()` to `toJS()` allowed it to work. Makes sense! Thanks!